# What's wrong with my "pixels[center_x + x, center_y + y] = pixel" syntax?

Tags: python

I wanted to manually copy lines from another array to the pygame framebuffer. With the help of the code below.

```
pixels = pygame.PixelArray(window)
center_x = (WINDOW_W - W) / 2
center_y = (WINDOW_H - H) / 2
for y in range(H):
    for x in range(W):
        pixel = gradient[x + y * W]
        pixel = (((pixel & 0x0000ff << 16) |
                 (pixel & 0x00ff00) |
                 ((pixel & 0xff0000) >> 16))

        pixels[center_x + x, center_y + y] = pixel
```

Python, however, spat out a syntax error.

```
    pixels[center_x + x, center_y + y] = pixel
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I tried the following methods, but none of them worked.

```
pixels['center_x' + 'x', 'center_y' + 'y'] = pixel

pixels[(center_x) + (x), (center_y) + (y) = pixel
```

I think the error could also be here when I declared the pixels variable.

```
pixels = pygame.PixelArray(window)
```

Where **window** is a reference to module **pygame**

```
window = pygame.display.set_mode([WINDOW_W, WINDOW_H], 0, 24)
```

Comment: I think the problem with the statement above that line. Are you sure there are not too many brackets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This statement has missing close paranthesis:

```
pixel = (((pixel & 0x0000ff << 16) |
          (pixel & 0x00ff00) |
          ((pixel & 0xff0000) >> 16))
```

Fixed statement:

```
(((pixel & 0x0000ff) << 16) |
  (pixel & 0x00ff00) |
 ((pixel & 0xff0000) >> 16))
```